# Enable stickiness and stickiness duration in Target group attributes of ALB Load balancer using ebextensions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ebextensions

I am looking at a way to enable stickiness and stickiness duration in Target group attributes of ALB Load balancer using ebextensions. I want to avoid mentioning Target Group name or VPCid in ebextension as the name might change later. In general, I want the setting to apply to whatever target group gets created. Can anyone guide on how it can be accomplished.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-environmentprocess

Comment: Hi we tried updating in beanstalk processes , but that did not work. We saw that setting it manually in Target group attributes work for us. So wanted to check if same can be done using ebexxtensions